# computed property names and this - JS

Tags: javascript, computed-properties

Can i use `this` in computed property name ?
something like this:

```
class User {
  constructor(username) {
    this._username = username;
  }

  [this._username + "Print"]() {
    console.log(this._username);
  }
}

const u = new User("MORA");
u.moraPrint(); // ?
```

And i know that it is useless in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define your function in your constructor, it can be done:

```js
class User {
  constructor(username) {
    this._username = username;
    this[username + "Print"] = function () {
    console.log(this._username);
    
    }
  }
}



const u = new User("mora");
u.moraPrint(); // ?
```

A class function can be created with computed property name, but as mentioned in comment `this` would not have been initialized by then, because there is no object instance.

You can check that by running this (pun intended) code :

```js
item = 'hey'
class User {
  constructor(username) {
    this._username = username;
  }

  [this.item + "hello"]() {
    console.log('hello ' + this._username);
  }
}

const u = new User("MORA");
u.heyhello(); // ?
```

The value of this is different because at the time code is run, the context is different.